# how do i change the name of the parent node of tree view that is linked to a wizard

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview that when double clicked loads a wizard which has a textbox that should rename the parent node of the treeview.

[Here is the image that shows how the **parentnode is supposed to get renamed** after i **click the finish wizard** which fetches the node name from a textbox named new project name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMAcO.png)

Here is the code snippet for the wizard button finish:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) //Wizard page finish button
    {
        con.Open();
        String query = "Insert into Project_details values ('" + textnewproid.Text + "','" + textprojname.Text + "','" + textbuilt.Text + "','" + textrevno.Text + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show(textprojname.Text);
        SERVER myopc = new SERVER(); //Main form
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Project_details where Proj_name='" + textprojname.Text + "'",con); 
        DataSet myds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(myds,"Project_details"); //Project_details is the table that contains values
        foreach (DataRow dr in myds.Tables["Project_details"].Rows) //throws exception
        {
            TreeNode parent = new TreeNode();
            parent.Text = dr["proj_name"].ToString();
            parent.ContextMenuStrip = myopc.contextMenuStrip1;
            myopc.treeView1.Nodes.Add(parent);
        }
        con.Close();
        this.Close();
    }
```

After i click the finish button i encounter a null reference exception which says Object refernce not set to an instance of an object.

Project Details Db contains 4 columns:
Proj_id,Proj_name,Proj_built,Proj_rev

Comment: We (obviously) need to know: Which line throws the exception???

Comment: You need to properly fill the dataset! Your constructor looks seriously [wrong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7se64052%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You should feed in the name, not an sql select!!

Comment: @TaW how about now is it correct?

Comment: Well it looks a lot better.. Does it also work better??? Don't keep us guessing! - Do use the debugger to look into each variable in a line that throws an exception! There you can see if the Table got created and how many rows it has etc..

Comment: @TaW it debugs properly without changing the name of the root node...it doesn't throws exception....are there any treeview properties that might help me to change the name of the treeview during runtime pls suggest..

Comment: 1) let's not call the Text the 'Name'. 2) you also clear the nodes. Does this show? Do any new nodes show? If not: Are you sure you have a valid reference to the right tv? How did th wizard get the form reference? -  You can also add a string to the Text as a sanity check.. Again, use the debugger to look into these things; we can do it for you..

Comment: You have removed the line which was clearing of the Nodes. Now the code will only __add__ new nodes. If you want to __keep__ the existing nodes but __change__ the Text of each of them you need some way to __identify__ them! Instead of creating new TreeNodes you should find the right node and set its Text. Finding the right ones is up to you..!

Answer (score 0):

```
      **possibilities Issued**
```

1 ) Check whether `dr["proj_name"].ToString()`  gives you the value or not.

2) i have noticed that you have initialized once and calling everytime 
   code :-

```
 SERVER myopc = new SERVER(); //initialized once  
foreach (DataRow dr in myds.Tables["Project_details"].Rows)
    {
        TreeNode parent = new TreeNode();
        parent.Text = dr["proj_name"].ToString();
        parent.ContextMenuStrip = myopc.contextMenuStrip1;//myopc called many times
        myopc.treeView1.Nodes.Add(parent);//same here myopc
    }
```

3) need to look at " Parent Object" can you update the problem with Parent code

```
 parent.ContextMenuStrip = myopc.contextMenuStrip1 //this statement need to look
```