# Can an existing treenode be renamed by fetching a value from database and replacing it with the node's name using windowsform?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Basically i have a winform **that contains a treeview** which **adds a new node on a button click**. So the new node that is created has a **mouse click event which pops up a wizard** that would contains all the details regarding the new node.  After all the details have been filled up the last page of the wizard would save the data into the database after the **finish button click** and **would retrieve a particular value from the table** which contains the project name entered into the project_name textbox and would use this value to rename the rootnode of treeview. I have tried everything to rename the rootnode by fetching the value from the table but all in vain.
Here is the code snippet for the finish button click.

[I am attaching the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZI1B.png)

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    String query = "Insert into Project_details values ('" + textnewproid.Text + "','" + textprojname.Text + "','" + textbuilt.Text + "','" + textrevno.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(textprojname.Text);
    this.Close();
    SERVER myopc = new SERVER(); //My main form that contains the treeview
    SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("Select Proj_name from Project_details  ", con); //Proj_name is the column that contains the value that is supposed to rename the node inside the table Project_details

    try
    {
        SqlDataReader myreader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myreader.Read())
        {
        TreeNode parentnode = new TreeNode(myreader["Proj_name"].ToString());
        myopc.treeView1.Nodes.Add(parentnode);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

So after i finish the wizard the node name does not change and remain the same and also i have searched the whole internet but i could only come up with the treelabel edit using contextmenu strip but that does not apply in my case as i do not need a contextmenu to rename the node..Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you keep calling the node.Text its 'name'?? This is wrong and misleading. Also: As [I have told you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921039/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-the-parent-node-of-tree-view-that-is-linked-to-a-wiz) the actual problem is not changing the Text but identifying the Node. I recommend passing out or keeping a reference to it somewhere..! - Note that your code doesn't __change__ anything. It creates a new Node. This may or may not be ok.. - Also, again: How do you open the wizard? How does it get its reference to the tree?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is editing the `TreeNode.Text` from your wizard and if you open the wizard by clicking on the `TreeNode`, why not write it as this:

```
if (myopc.treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
    myopc.treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = myreader["Proj_name"].ToString();
```

Note that `TreeNode` also has a `Name` property, which as with all controls is not really useful: It is just a string, not displayed, not guaranteed to be unique and not able to work as an Indexer..

To change it you would write:

```
someTreeNode.Name = "Donald";
```

Comment: For somebody seeking help __you are not helpful__ in resolving your own problems.  The __very least__ you should do is answer questions we ask you and describe __exactly__ what happens. You should use the debugger and report the findings from it! - . _i tried the if statement_ So? And then? Was there a SelectedNode ? -  I have tested the code and it works just fine here..

Comment: I meant that i tried the if statement and i guess that the treenode wasnt able to fetch the data coz the wizard wasnt able to fetch the instance of the treenode. So my question is how do i get the instance of the treenode to another form which is my wizard form.